# Linq: Date less that x, but next record date is greater that x

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I got records in database. Each record has field "Date". 
For given date=x i need to find records that Date value is less that x, but next record date is greater of x.

Example:

```
id  date
--------------
1   12.03.2013
2   15.03.2013
3   18.03.2013
```

now, I got `X=16.03.2013`, and i need a LINQ that return this record:

```
 2  15.03.2013
```

BUT! for the `X=15.03.2014` it should return nothing (because there is record with smaller date, but next record has exactly the same date as X)

How can i do this?

Comment: "Next" by what measure? Next by ID?

Comment: So, if you have your dates ordered, there will at most be one date which is less than a given date and the next date record is greater than that given date.

Comment: Please see the edit and comment on my answer. Depending on the requirements, you may need to unaccept...

Comment: @JonSkeet - that's no problem,After query I manually check if the record is the newest (in matter of date, ofc), and exclude it if it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach IMO is just to find the record that it *would* find, and check the date afterwards:

```
var result = db.Table
               .Where(x => x.Date <= target.Date)
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
               .FirstOrDefault();
if (result != null && result.Date == target.Date)
{
    result = null;
}
```

Or you *could* do it all in the query using a secondary `Where` clause after filtering to a single result:

```
var result = db.Table
               .Where(x => x.Date <= target.Date)
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
               .Take(1)
               .Where(x => x.Date != target.Date)
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that this *doesn't* work if all values are less than `x` (so there's no "next" record at all). I haven't yet worked out a way to handle that.

Comment: What is result for *19.03.2013*? Consider checking is any date bigger than X exists.

Comment: @MarcinJ: Ah, yes - I'd misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

If all values can be less than x then you can use

```
var candidate = dates.Where(x => x.Date < target.Date)
                   .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
    var next = dates.Where(x => x.Date >= target.Date)
                   .OrderBy(x => x.Date)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
     return (candite != null && next != null && next.Date != target.Date) ? candidate : null
```